# Splitting a number of lines in a text file into equal pieces based on the category in one column?

Tags: bash, text

I have a file.txt that is looks like this:

```
Name        Value
Individual1 1
Individual1 2 
Individual1 4
Individual2 23
Individual2 232
Individual2 15
Individual3 6
Individual3 8
Individual3 09
... and so on...
```

I'd like to split each individual into a separate file for each individual. Such that Individual1.txt looks like:

```
Individual1 1
Individual1 2 
Individual1 4
```

and Individual2.txt Looks like:

```
Individual2 23
Individual2 232
Individual2 15
```

I know there's a bash command out there that's simple and striaght-forward for this, but what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'FNR>1 {print > $1".txt"}' file.txt
```

Comment: This is a really elegant line, but would you mind explaining what's going on? If I were to create this I would think to use the append >> pipe instead. How is it able to write each line like that and overiding each time

Comment: `FNR` is number of lines for each input file (here only `file.txt`). Only if FNR is larger 1 execute part in curly brackets to exclude your headline. `print > $1".txt"` redirect complete line to a file. This awk syntax create the file and append every line to this file. If the file exists, it is overwritten.